# Tracking down mysterious session-ending bug

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm using Codeigniter/PyroCMS which uses ion_auth.

I have my session stuff set for two hours. I'm using db sessions.

There is a gremlin somewhere that is booting the session after n minutes, sometimes. It is very random, and as such is <strike>hard</strike> impossible to reliably reproduce.

I've added log entries to the Session class (specifically sess_destroy) but that merely logs the session being destroyed, which I already knew.

I tried to add a debug_backtrace() into said log entry, but that aint jiving with teh codes (it doesn't get logged/it spits it onto the screen for a split second before the !session redirect).

Is there a good/proper way to track this down?

Thanks guise.

---

update: I added a few more log entries in Session.php Turns out the db session is being deleted/overwritten incorrectly. WHAI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been an issue with the server and resolve.conf mapping things incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a problem quite common. I have used (and happily accepted as recommendation)
[Codeigniter's Native session](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session) (there is a download link at the bottom)

BUT, due that it is an old library you MUST made some hacks. You can check those simple hacks in the [library's forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103583/P30/#910927)

Just drop this file in codeigniter's library directory and see if resolve your problem. Please feedback.

Comment: Problem is the framework I'm using (PyroCMS) depends on ion_auth. Thanks.

Comment: @stormdrain I have used pyrocms to build a big site `r.gd` Precisely in that framework I used the library I talked about it. Did you tried it? The problem was the same: unstable sessions.

Comment: Interesting. Did the site incorporate the pyro admin panel? I thought the functionality in there was closely tied to ion_auth (new/edit users, etc). Thanks again.

Comment: @stormdrain Yes, the site use the pyro admin panel for admins. And yes, pyro is very tied to ion_auth (with many hacks of `phil`) But this `session` library is transparent to it.

Comment: Updated Native Session link here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session

The forum link doesn't work for me either. Are the hacks necessary the same ones described at the bottom of the above link?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your session cookie is prematurely expiring. Start by checking the settings in your config file for your session related stuff. Namely the $config['sess_expiration'] value, which defaults to 7200. Which is 2 hours.

Then check your php.ini, which I believe defaults to 3600. (1 hr)

Otherwise, I would say that if your code is on a unix system, try a

```
grep -Rn 'sess_destroy' .
```

The other thing you might want to look for is anyplace that is attempting to possibly write NULLs or empty values to the session. It's possible that you don't have a sess_destroy anywhere, but that you could have something to the effect of unset($_SESSION).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not expiring early as a result of some cofiguration as then it would be expiring consistently after `n` time. Session expiration is set in the config to two hours. php.ini is configured correctly.

Comment: Do you have a cron job running that perhaps is doing some sort of work related to the /tmp directory where sessions are stored? If those session files are being deleted then say goodbye to any active sessions regardless of expiration.

Comment: No. According to more logs, the db session is being deleted (or a new session initiated which isn't authenticated. I grepped around and did not find any $_SESSION candidates for my problem. I also added logging to all sess_destroy()'s, and saw that it's called when the db session goes missing, but can't find what is deleting said db session. Thanks.